# How to grep on the first column of tab-delimited piped output? Subset?

Tags: python, linux, grep, pipe

After other operations, I am essentially `cat`ing a file, which outputs in tab-delimited format.

There are columns

```
$ cat file.txt 
longstring1:with:semicolons    ERFVBNMNBFGHNMKJHNMH    1:2:2:2:2    -
secondline:is:here    VHNBVFTYHNBGHJMKJHJMN    0:0:0:0:0    -
third:canbefound:here    VFTYHBVFGHJNJGVGHJKMNGB    4:1:0:1:0    -
```

(1) Piping this output into `grep`, how could I grep on only the first column in order to

```
$ cat file.txt | grep first_column > new_out.txt
```

In this case, as I would be `grep`ing on each row of the first column from  the piped output of `cat file.txt`, the file `new_out.txt` should be the same as `file.txt`.

(2) Is there a way with command line tools to do grep on the first column based on some condition?

I would like to grep the first column row only if the third column contains non-zero elements. Is this possible, or should I use some scripting language (e.g. Python)?

In this case, the operation would be something like

```
$ cat file.txt | grep first_column if some_condition > new_out.txt
```

In this case, `new_out.txt` would contain only the first and third row.

Comment: *if the third **row*** - you meant column, I suppose

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Yes, edited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue.

Case (1), filtering according to the values in the first column (`$1`):

```
$ awk -F'\t' '$1~"here" {print}' file
secondline:is:here    VHNBVFTYHNBGHJMKJHJMN    0:0:0:0:0    -
third:canbefound:here    VFTYHBVFGHJNJGVGHJKMNGB    4:1:0:1:0    -
```

(Where we print the complete line if the first column, `$1`, contains the pattern/string `here`.)

Case (2), filter according to the values in the first column, but only if the third column contains at least one non-zero element:

```
$ awk -F'\t' '$3~/(^|:)[1-9]+(:|$)/ && $1~"here" {print}' file
third:canbefound:here    VFTYHBVFGHJNJGVGHJKMNGB    4:1:0:1:0    -
```

(Where in addition to the condition from the previous case, we ensure the third column, `$3`, contains the pattern `:<one_or_more_digits_except_zero>:`, with the starting colon `:` is omitted on the start and end of the value.)

Comment: Thanks! For future readers, maybe it's best to show you're not excluding the first row---it might cause confusion. `longstring1:with:semicolons    ERFVBNMNBFGHNMKJHNMH    1:2:2:2:2 `

Comment: You're welcome! Yes, the first row is not printed in the case #1 because it doesn't contain string `here` in the first column.

Comment: Right, that's what I meant. Clarifying that is helpful; otherwise, awk noobs might have "here" in all of their scripts. (You never know...)

Comment: One other question: I'm piping the output above, not saving it in a `file.txt`. Imagine instead of `file.txt`, I was piping the equivalent to STDIN via a pipe `|`. How do I `awk` this (i.e. without the intermediate txt file)?

Comment: You can chain `awk` in the pipeline in the standard way: `cat file | awk '..' | cmd`. Just omit the `file` argument from `awk` call.

Answer (score 1):

> to grep the first column row only if the third column contains
>   non-zero elements

```
awk '$3~/[1-9]/{ print $1 }' file.txt > new_out.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

using **awk**

```
$ awk ' $3!~/0:0:0:0:0/{print}' file
longstring1:with:semicolons    ERFVBNMNBFGHNMKJHNMH    1:2:2:2:2    -
third:canbefound:here    VFTYHBVFGHJNJGVGHJKMNGB    4:1:0:1:0
```

If you want to search anything in first column say the word **with** then you can modify it to :

```
$ awk ' $3!~/0:0:0:0:0/ && $1~/with/{print}' file
longstring1:with:semicolons    ERFVBNMNBFGHNMKJHNMH    1:2:2:2:2    -
```

Comment: The OP meant only the first and third row would be considered in case #2, not columns `$1` and `$3` printed.